# How to acsess the session variable in forms.py outside of Formclass in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new to django

I need to create dropdown in form and the dropdown needs to update with values from the database based on some lookup . The look up will change based on the request

Here is the code

```
from django import forms
from .models import Configuration
from django.db.models import Q
from configuration.models import Configuration
def getschema():
    x=[]
    #change the hardcoded 8 here
    allschema = Configuration.objects.filter(project_id = request.session['project_id'])
    for schema in allschema:
        print(schema.schema_name)
        x.append((schema.schema_name,schema.schema_name))
    return x

class TestCaseForm(forms.Form):
    TestcaseName = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": "Test Case Name",
                "name" : "testcasename",
            }))
    TestcaseDescription = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": "Test Case Description",
                "name" : "testcasedesc",
            }))
    SourceSchema= forms.CharField(label='Select Source Schema', widget=forms.Select(choices=getschema(),attrs={"name": "srcschema"}))
    TargetSchema= forms.CharField(label='Select Target Schema', widget=forms.Select(choices=getschema(),attrs={"name": "srcschema"}))
    SourceQuery = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "rows":4, "cols":50,
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Source query",
            "name": "sourcequery",
        }))
    TargetQuery = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "rows":4, "cols":50,
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Target query",
            "name": "targetquery",
        }))

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            self.request = kwargs.pop('request',None)
            super(TestCaseForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    def clean(self):
            print(self.request.user.id)
```

My question is how to use  the session object inside my getschema() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the choices depend on the request, you should initialise them in your form's `__init__()` method, not in the class attribute. Also you don't need to do that with the widget, if you make them a `ModelChoiceField` instead of a `CharField`:

```
class TestCaseForm(forms.Form):
    # remove SourceSchema since the queryset cannot be determined when the class is initialised

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['SourceSchema']= forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Configuration.objects.filter(
                project_id = request.session['project_id']
            )
        )
```

Note that by default this will use the `__str__()` method of your `Configuration` model to represent the objects in the drop-down. If you want to have a different representation, then you should subclass `ModelChoiceField` and use that in your form:

```
class ConfigurationChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, configuration):
        return configuration.schema_name
```

Comment: @user3048099 then you should mark this answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new variable for the session object and pass it to the getschema()